# How do you make a complement symbol?

Tags: discussion

I've often seen a notation where there is a horizontal bar over a letter to indicate the inverted value of something, e.g. q and (not)q for the outputs of a flip-flop. The not q would be a q with a bar over it.

More recently I was trying to describe the inputs to a 16 bit ADC, where one of the lines was R/(not)C.

I just waded through page after page of Unicode but could not find Roman letters with bars over them, except a few vowels.

Is there a way to do that in a Stack Exchange post?

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question/1245#1245

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax/216607#216607

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like \$\overline{this}\$?

Just invoke the `\overline` command in MathJax:

```
You mean like \$\overline{this}\$?
```

To have it not italicized you can use `\text{}` like in \$\overline{\text{this}}\$.

```
\$\overline{\text{this}}\$
```

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what I mean. (voted.) Will that work on other Stack Exchange sites like Stack Overflow or the Arduino SO Beta? What kind of markup is that?

Comment: I think it's pretty universal across all SE sites. It's called "MathJax", and it's based on LaTeX. There's plenty of documentation in the SE help and on the web in general.

Comment: @DaveTweed since the engine is quite heavy, I think it only works here, on math and perhaps physics

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128228/latex-on-stack-overflow-for-dummies/128232#128232

Comment: @clabacchio: After reading through that thread, and a few others linked to it, it would seem that there's more than just a few SE sites that currently have MathJax enabled. I guess we'd need to talk to an SE employee to get a definitive list.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work on the Arduino SE site. Pity. I posted a feature request on the Arduino Meta SE asking for a way to enter this notation somehow. MathJax seems like a decent option.

Comment: It doesn't really matter all that much. There are many commonly-understood ways to denote an active-low signal, including `/SIGNAL`, `SIGNAL-` and `SIGNAL_L`. Just pick one and go with it.

Comment: There's a community maintained list of sites with MathJax support here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax

Comment: @DuncanC - It greatly reduces pageload speed, so unless there is a major need they try to avoid it. Just for a not in logic would not be reasonable.

Comment: I've added the non-italicized version, I hope you don't mind ;)